# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE lines terminated by /n

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have the following code to write to a file:

```
 each_file.write(url+"|*|"+rep_name+'|*|'+b['_source']['dataset']['ID']+'|*|'+ title+ '|*|'+ description+"\n")
```

Then, I will load this file into MySql using:

```
cursor.execute ("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE testseprator FIELDS TERMINATED by '|*|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (link,repo_name,dataset_id,title,description) SET id = NULL" %(file1,))
```

which file1 refers to my file path.
Now, as you can see in the screenshot below:[image: output screenshot]

there is lots of new lines in my file, now, when I insert this data into MySql the table is messed up! I have description text into my link column, ....
I think, it is because of new lines that I have in description! how can I fix this problem? I used description1=str(description.strip().strip("")), but, this did not help!

Comment: Try making the query a raw string.

Comment: @Barmar can you please explain what you mean by raw string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa